# Nuxt progress bar keeps blinking (keeps removing and appending itself from the dom)

Tags: vue.js, progress-bar, loading, nuxt.js

thank you for opening up this post.

Hope someone can help me with this annoying issue.

My progress bar on Nuxt app keeps 'blinking'... keeps removing and appending itself from the DOM.

Please see video: https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cqXZ01U4m2

I'm running axios and querying graphql on successful login.

I don't think the loader is suppose to be behaving this way, shouldn't it append once, gradually bring width property from 0% to 100% and then remove it self?

I would very much appreciate if anyone can help out with this.

Comment: You might need to post a minimum reproducible example.  Your configuration looks fine, and it looks like you're using a scaffolded project, so I can only assume there's something wrong in one of the pages or supporting components that's causing this.

Comment: Haven't worked on this for a while, but tonight I found the issue... I had multiple graphql request firing one after another, so flickering was happening basically because of that.
I didn't realize Nuxt would do that, thought it would have one long loading bar for all requests... Still I'm currently stuck with two bars blinking, one for loading request, one for loading the page.
It would be nice if I could bundle those two into one loading bar.